# PyBuilder - how to continue when tests fail or coverage is too low?

Tags: python, unit-testing, build, pybuilder

Coming from maven it would be nice to have a configuration option in pybuilder that allows me to continue when tests are failing or test coverage is too low.

I'm wondering if such an option exists - didn't find it in documentation:
[PyBuilder Plugins Documentation](http://pybuilder.github.io/documentation/plugins.html)

Background:
I plan to use pybuilder in jenkins and publish my test results in sonar, while still being able to upload development artifacts to our internal repository. All of that doesn't work, if the build stops on test failures or too low coverage.

Answer (score 3):

The test coverage part of the question is solved:

There is a property, which can be set in build.py:

```
@init
def set_properties(project):
    project.set_property('coverage_break_build', False)
```

Found via `pyb -X` - which prints out a lot of config values.